# Once I have shared something from my android app, How to logout from face book in my application?

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have developed a game on unity 3d for android that has the functionality to share the score on Facebook. If I am not logged in to the native android facebook app then my game  asks the user to sign in by opening the facebook sign in page. once user is signed in his score is shared on the facebook on his wall.

Ok now the problem is after all that I have mentioned above, I logout the facebook. And when again I try to share the score on facebook  my game opens the last user's facebook  account. That should not happen, If I have logged out , my game should reopen the facebook login page and ask me to sign in again... What should I do to remove the last used  account from my game? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly log the user out from the Facebook app, only from your own app.

In your specific use case, you can potentially use SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO when you're opening the session, which forces a web dialog for login, and does not use the Facebook app.